# Halting Problem - Arguments to Halting Checker Function

Tags: halting-problem

I'm trying to understand the Halting Problem. All the explanations I've seen state that the problem arises when passing a program to a halting check function along with itself as input. For example `if halts(program, program)` in the code below (please let me know if my code does not accurately represent the halting problem).

One thing that is confusing me is why we need to stipulate that the program is passed to the harting checker along with itself as input.

If, for example, we had `if halts(program, "foo")`, would the paradox no longer occur?

````
def halts(program, input_data):
    """
    Hypothetical function.
    Returns True if program would halt when run with input_data
    as its input, else False.
    """

    return program_halts


def will_i_halt(program):
    if halts(program, program):
        while True:
            print("INFINITE LOOP")
    else:
        print("HALT")


will_i_halt(will_i_halt)
```
````

Answer (score 2):

I can write a program "halts" which will often return the correct result, will never return the wrong result, and will sometimes not halt.

For example, programs without loops and recursion always halt. So I can write a program "halts" that checks if another program has no loops and recursions and returns "halts" if that is the case, but if there is a loop then my program can't figure out the correct answer, so to avoid ever giving the wrong answer it just doesn't halt.

There is nothing deep or interesting in the answer so far, it is just all straightforward and obvious. I could improve the program, for example to see if the program runs into a loop from which it cannot exit and return "doesn't halt" in that case, so it might indeed work in a useful way for *many* cases.

Now the question is: Is there a program "halts" which will always return the correct result, and *never* halt? We can either write such a program and prove that is correct, or we can prove that such a program doesn't exist.

To prove that "halts" cannot exist, we could try to find inputs where a human can't figure out whether "program" halts with input "input_data" or not. But that's problematic; the human might just not be clever enough, and a more clever human might figure out whether this program halts, or be able to write the program "halts", because they are more clever.

The other possibility is to prove "if 'halts" existed, then I could give it inputs where I can prove that it returned the wrong results".

At the moment I don't know if program "will_i_halt" will halt with input "will_i_halt". But *if* it halts, and the program "halts" is correct, then will_i_halt(will_i_halt) calls halts(will_i_halt, will_i_halt) which returns true, and then then will_i_halt goes into an infinite loop. So *if* it halts, "halts" cannot have returned the correct result.

If it doesn't halt, then will_i_halt(will_i_halt) calls halts(will_i_halt, will_i_halt) which returns "no" and will_i_halt halts. So if it doesn't halt, "halts" cannot have returned the correct result either. Since a program either halts or doesn't, we found an input where "halts" gives the wrong result. Contradiction therefore "halts" doesn't exist.

We need to call will_i_halt(will_i_halt) because doing this produces the identical call twice with different results. The results of calling will_i_halt(will_i_halt) directly and calling it indirectly by calling halts(will_i_halt, will_i_halt) are different.

If I called will_i_halt(foo) that would call halts(foo, foo) which would call foo(foo). Quite obvious that calling will_i_halt(foo) and foo(foo) should produce different results, so whatever halts(foo, foo) produces doesn't give any contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm still digesting.

Comment: I think you mean the program "halts" *always* halts, not never. (paragraph 4)

Answer (score 1):

You are asking an interesting question.

For one, start by fully understanding the halting problem and the proof of its undecidability (from what it sounds you *do* understand it).

Now, you are asking what happens when we restrict ourselves to a specific input for the turing machines? The answer is quite interesting - even in this case the problem is undecidable!

The "trick" is to somehow encode *both* the turing machine *and* its input together, and pass it as the first "program" parameter. This is done as follows:

Given a TM $M$ and an input $w$, construct the new machine $M_w$. The machine $M_w$ will ignore its input, and will simply simulate $M$ when ran with $w$ as its input.

Now, notice that running this $M_w$ with any input, for example even with "foo" as the input - will be equivalent to running $M$ with $w$ as its input. Hence, deciding if $M_w$ halts when given input "foo" is equivalent to deciding whether $M$ halts on $w$ (which we know is an undecidable problem).